# Reset to custom offset in Kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka, stream-processing, apache-samza

I am researching Kafka for a specific use case I am working on. I have a stream of data that is flowing and I want to process it and publish it to intermediary stages.

At each of these stages *(initial and intermediary)* Samza tasks would do the processing and re publishing. One of the requirements I have is for me to be able to re-trigger the whole processing pipeline from a specific stage in time whenever I want.

I know that kafka maintains an offset for each of its logs *(incoming data)*. However, does Kafka provide any functionality with which I can ***map*** partition offsets to some custom identifier *(say timestamp)* and use this to re-trigger the whole pipeline from that point on wards?

I have read in multiple places that I can replay the kafka commit log by resetting it the beginning and also going back some N times. But is there a way for me to map these offsets to my own identifier like time stamps and use it as a mechanism to tell from which offset to replay.

Best
Shabir

Answer (score 2):

you can use commandline tool kafka-consumer-groups to reset offset for consumer group based on timestamp (--to-datetime). See more on the doc page: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group

The same, of course, can be achieved through the code.

Comment: Thank you. This is sort of what I was expecting. Is there some Kafka SDK that lets us directly access this information from code and re-configure the offset?

Comment: Also can I tag offsets with my own field so when I say run from this vlaue of this field it will pick the correct offset?

Comment: https://medium.com/@werneckpaiva/how-to-seek-kafka-consumer-offsets-by-timestamp-de351ba35c61 check this post how to do this in the code

Comment: as far as I know, Kafka doesn't allow you to put any 'tags' on offsets. You are free to implement that on your own using any DB (something like table: topic, partition, offset -> tag)